# How can I setup multiple php version in Linux?

Tags: linux, php

I am working on a project and I just want to ask on how can I setup multiple PHP version in Linux. The scenario looks something like this since the server already has a PHP but with a version of 5.2 wherein it cannot support the project that I am currently doing. So what I did, I download a PHP version of 5.3 since my project can handle this, and the problem now is how can I set it up in the Linux. How could I possibly do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to use a separate instance of httpd / apache / nginx.

Comment: how can I suppose to do this?

Comment: I've search a lot and I found something like fastcgi, how could I do this? sorry I am just new to this.

Comment: ahhh,,,,, okies,, but how can I implement this to different version in one server? can u help me? by the way the project I a working on is using symfony2 and since the requirements of symfony is php version 5.3 and above and the server php version is only 5.2